# Merge Multiple Row into One according to certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

I have data like this:

### STARTDATE ENDDATE AMOUNT INVNO

- 2012-11-07 09:23:48.000  2012-11-07
  09:23:59.000 0.00000000  000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 09:23:59.000  2012-11-07
  10:14:02.000 0.00000000  000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 10:14:02.000  2012-11-07
  10:15:13.000 0.00000000  000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 10:15:13.000  2012-11-07
  10:34:08.000 0.00000000  000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 10:34:08.000  2012-11-07
  11:09:33.000 4000.00000000   000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 11:09:33.000  2012-11-07
  11:10:35.000 4000.00000000   000000000002012

and I want them into one row merging like this:

- 2012-11-07 09:23:48.000  2012-11-07
  11:10:35.000 8000.00000000   000000000002012
  first row's start date in STARTDATE field, last row's end date in ENDDATE field and SUM of amount in AMOUNT field.

thanks for helping

ps: But if there is a data start date isnt same previous row's end date, it has to start new row.like this:

- 2012-11-07 09:23:48.000   2012-11-07
  09:23:59.000 20.00000000 000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 09:23:59.000   2012-11-07
  10:14:02.000 30.00000000 000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 10:16:09.000   2012-11-07
  10:19:13.000 40.00000000 000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 10:19:13.000   2012-11-07
  10:34:08.000 50.00000000 000000000002012

should be like this:

- 2012-11-07 09:23:48.000   2012-11-07
  10:14:02.000 50.00000000 000000000002012
- 2012-11-07 10:16:09.000   2012-11-07
  10:34:08.000 90.00000000 000000000002012

Comment: What format is data in? Excel, RDBMS or something else? Also, what do you mean by "first" and "last" rows? Is there a field onto which you're sorting them? Also what operation is being done on the 4th column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample data - I've changed the invoice number of your second example to ...13 to distinguish it.

```
--DROP TABLE #LINES
CREATE TABLE #Lines(
STARTDATE datetime, 
ENDDATE datetime, 
AMOUNT money,
INVNO varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Lines
SELECT 
'2012-11-07 09:23:48.000', '2012-11-07 09:23:59.000', 0.00000000, 000000000002012
UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 09:23:59.000', '2012-11-07 10:14:02.000', 0.00000000, 000000000002012
UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 10:14:02.000', '2012-11-07 10:15:13.000', 0.00000000, 000000000002012
UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 10:15:13.000', '2012-11-07 10:34:08.000', 0.00000000, 000000000002012
UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 10:34:08.000', '2012-11-07 11:09:33.000', 4000.00000000, 000000000002012
UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 11:09:33.000', '2012-11-07 11:10:35.000', 4000.00000000, 000000000002012

UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 09:23:48.000', '2012-11-07 09:23:59.000', 20.00000000, 000000000002013
UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 09:23:59.000', '2012-11-07 10:14:02.000', 30.00000000, 000000000002013
UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 10:16:09.000', '2012-11-07 10:19:13.000', 40.00000000, 000000000002013
UNION ALL SELECT
'2012-11-07 10:19:13.000', '2012-11-07 10:34:08.000', 50.00000000, 000000000002013
```

Then try this

```
;
WITH 
    InvGroupStartDates AS
    (
        select
            InvGroupStartDate = L1.STARTDATE, 
            L1.INVNO, 
            INVGroupNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY L1.INVNO ORDER BY L1.StartDate )
        from #Lines L1
        where not exists(
            select *
            from #Lines L2
            where L1.ENDDATE = L2.STARTDATE
            and L1.INVNO = L2.INVNO
            )
    ),

    InvGroupRanges AS
    (
        select 
            IGSD1.INVNO, 
            IGSD1.InvGroupStartDate, 
            InvGroupEndDateEx = IGSD2.InvGroupStartDate
        from InvGroupStartDates IGSD1
            left join InvGroupStartDates IGSD2
                on IGSD1.INVNO = IGSD2.INVNO
                and IGSD1.INVGroupNo = IGSD2.INVGroupNo - 1
    )
SELECT 
    STARTDATE = InvGroupRanges.InvGroupStartDate,
    INVNO = InvGroupRanges.INVNO,
    ENDDATE = MAX( L.ENDDATE ),
    AMOUNT = SUM( L.Amount )
from #Lines L
    inner join InvGroupRanges
        on L.STARTDATE >= InvGroupRanges.InvGroupStartDate
        and ( InvGroupRanges.InvGroupEndDateEx is NULL OR L.ENDDATE < InvgroupRanges.InvGroupEndDateEx )
group by InvGroupRanges.InvGroupStartDate, InvGroupRanges.INVNO
```

The code determines the start of the invoice line ranges (same invoice number, only getting those without a previous line).  It then gets the end of the invoice line ranges - the end date is NOT inclusive as it's the start of the subsequent range.

Finally it uses these start/end invoice line range date lines to get your data.

Comment: STARTDATE INVNO ENDDATE AMOUNT
2012-11-07 11:09:33.000 2012 2012-11-07 11:10:35.000 4000.00
2012-11-07 09:23:59.000 2013 2012-11-07 10:15:13.000 30.00
2012-11-07 10:19:13.000 2013 2012-11-07 11:10:35.000 8050.00

Comment: these are results.should be like these :

STARTDATE INVNO ENDDATE AMOUNT
--------
2012-11-07 09:23:48.000 2012 2012-11-07 11:10:35.000 8000.00
2012-11-07 09:23:48.000 2013 2012-11-07 10:14:02.000 50.00
2012-11-07 10:16:09.000 2013 2012-11-07 10:34:08.000 90.00

Comment: I got this.I inspired from your sql.first view it gives me end dates and i wrote start dates sql , found ranges and joined original table then got results.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(startdate),max(enddate),sum(amount),INVNO 
       from T 
       group by INVNO
```

Comment: sorry for lack of information? 4th column remains same. because grouping is 4th column and valex it would be too easy that there is only data like this. But if there is a data start date isnt same previous row's end date, it has to start new row. ill give sample.